# Switch to Google Chrome app instead of opening a new window from command line in MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

Up until recently (before Feb 4th 2018 fo sure) I was able to switch focus to the active Google Chrome windows or run the app if it is not running with:

```
open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
```

Now the same command opens new window of Google Chrome instead of switching to the existing one.

I do not understand why it happens and why it changed all of a sudden. I did nothing special in between so it must be due to automatic updates of Google Chrome. How can I achieve previous behaviour?

I of course also searched for a solution but did not find anything relevant. I have tried to run Chrome directly with:

```
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

It gives the same result (opens new window) and I also got this message in the terminal:

```
Created new window in existing browser session.
[some strange numbers here:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] 
Failed to launch GPU process.
```

I do not understand this error but forums (e.g., [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2836)) suggest to do

```
export BROWSER=google-chrome
```

It did not work for me. So here I am asking for help)

(MacOS 10.13.3, Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119 installed with `brew cask install google-chrome`)

Comment: I have this problem too, I can't even hide the output with 2>&1 /dev/null or | grep "shutup"

I am guessing chrome is finding any open terminal and printing to it somehow.

Comment: @flcoder as a temporary solution try to toggle off **Use hardware acceleration when available** in Chrome settings. This solves the issue for me.

Comment: @Stas Thanks for the workaround. It also worked for me